# Error al abrir imagen con cv2.imread

Tags: python, python-3.x

Al intentar abrir una imagen con opencv desde python, tengo un error al usar

```
cv2.imread("C:\Developer\TEMP\t**í**lde\imagen\lena.jpg")
```

cuando la ruta de la imagen contiene caracteres con tilde "acento ortográfico".

Comment: El error no es de `imread` si no, de tu ruta es raro que tenga acentos una carpeta y más aun creo que es imposible reemplazar los acentos y aun asi, encontrar la ruta

Comment: O prueba usando el prefijo `r` antes del *string* para indicarle que lo quieres literal: `cv2.imread(r"C:\Developer\TEMP\t**í**lde\imagen\lena.jpg") `

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, y ya probé con las recomendaciones de sioesi, FJSevilla y kikocorreoso. Nullptr, aprovecho de preguntar, ¿ya encontraste algo para solucionar este inconveniente?.