# Error al usar el método imread sobre rutas o nombres de archivo con tilde

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2

imagen =  cv2.imread("./imagenes/fotografía.jpg")
cv2.imshow("imagen", imagen)
```

Al ejecutar este código, recibo el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\prueba.py", line 5, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("imagen", imagen)
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:325: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

El error se presenta siempre que en la ruta se encuentre una **tilde**, sin importar si es el nombre del archivo o del directorio.

Ya existe en StackOverflow una pregunta por el mismo motivo, pero ésta fue formulada hace más de dos años y no ha sido respondida:

[Error al abrir imagen con cv2.imread](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38745/error-al-abrir-imagen-con-cv2-imread)

Intenté con las recomendaciones de los comentarios, pero no funcionan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser que [`imread`/`imwrite` solo acepta rutas ascii](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4292). La única forma que se me ocurre de lidiar con esto es cargar la imagen en un array NumPy previamente y luego usar [`cv2.imdecode`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imdecode) que permite leer imágenes desde un buffer en memoria (un array NumPy):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_array = np.fromfile("./imagenes/fotografía.jpg", np.uint8)
imagen = cv2.imdecode(img_array, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

también se podría generar el array desde un objeto `bytearray`, lo cual puede ser útil también en otras situaciones (imagen desde url, desde cadena de bytes en memoria, etc):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

with  open("./imagenes/fotografía.jpg", "rb") as file:
    img_array = np.asarray(bytearray(file.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
imagen = cv2.imdecode(img_array, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias FJSevilla, funciona correctamente.